# angular-xeditable: Editable fields only for authenticated users

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got fascinated about how easy it is to use angular-xeditable and make values editable in place.

My question is how I can restrict what values/fields can be edited by what users. Im having three user groups and would like to restrict who can edit what fields.

Comment: looks that setting up `ng-disabled="condition"` can do the trick

Comment: Here is similar question to the author: https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/issues/73 And his solution http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/679/ But this way you'll have to add the class to each input. not DRY enough. It has to have some live flag in options.

Comment: Agree, this might be quick solution, but not DRY enough. I think it's strange that there are no authorization involved in current solution.